# Move a background position with jQuery

Tags: jquery, css

Trying to do something similar to this: [jQuery background-position animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3007180/jquery-background-position-animation) but not getting it to work. Wondered if anyone could help.

I've a jCarouselLite carousel on a page. I have a subnav to that jCarousel which has a little arrow at the top to indicate, this is the subnav related to the slide being shown in the carousel. As jCarouselLite doesn't have a feedback feature and it's too late in the project to change to another carousel, I need to see if I can get this working. I had thought I could use JS to move the background position on the same timed cycle as the banners, but it's not working.

Here's the JS I've done:

```
function bannav(){
        var sp = new Array(-880,-700,-520,-360,-180);
        var i=0;
        for(i===1;i<=5;i++){
            position = sp[i]+'px 0px';
            window.setInterval(function(){
                $('div.container div.banner-holder ul#controls').animate(function(){
                    $this.css('background-position', position);
                });
              }, 8000);
            if(i==5){i=0};
        }}
```

All it's doing is tying up the page. I'm blind from looking at it, so i I've done something really stupid, apologies in advance. Any help much appreciated.

T

Comment: should this for(i===1;i<=5;i++){
  just be for(i=1;i<=5;i++){

Comment: about to say the same :)

Comment: haha hate it when that happens!

Comment: it seems like you can get away with (i===1) - not sure if that is for a reason

Comment: you live and learn on SO even when offering answers :)

Comment: Thanks all, great input here. See my comment below TommyBs answer below. I've a lot more to work out...

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that 'this' is being passed incorrectly?

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en/window.setInterval and 'The 'this' problem'

Answer (score 0):

Looking at this with what's been mentioned above

```
  function bannav(){
    var sp = new Array(-880,-700,-520,-360,-180);
    var i=0;
    for(i=1;i<=5;i++){
        position = sp[i]+'px 0px';
        window.setInterval(function(){
            $('div.container div.banner-holder ul#controls').animate(function(){
                $(this).css('background-position', position);
            });
          }, 8000);
        if(i==5){i=0};
    }}
```

I've made a couple of changes here. 1 is I changed the for loop as in my previous comments. i ===1 is checking if i is equal to 1 and of the same type as i, I don't think that's what you want to do here, you are assigning the value for your for loop. Secondly off the back of the 'this' answer listed previously, in the context of jQuery I've changed this to be the jquery $(this) object that you were using .css on rather than being 'this' which in this case is now a reference to the correct jquery object (ul id="controls") I believe

Comment: Cheers Tommy. I've actually discovered I've a lot more wrong with it than just this. The setInterval will wait 8s but in the meantime the for loop will have finished. I need to re-address how I approach this... Thanks for the input though, much appreciated.